# perl pass in hidden credential file as parameter

Tags: perl, scripting

I have perl script that i'm working on. Here in the code I'm essentially opening up a file handle to create a parameter file like so:

```
my $date_string= strftime '%Y%m%d',gmtime;
my $par_file = "/tmp/$schema-$date_string.par";
open my $par_fh, '>', $par_file or die "$par_file: opening for write: $!";
print $par_fh << PAR;
USERID=MYUSER/MYPA55W0RD
DIRECTORY=DMPDIR
SCHEMA=$schema
DUMPFILE=$sechema-$date_string.dmp
CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
LOGFILE=$schema-$date_string.log
PAR
close $par_fh
    or die "$par_file: closing after write: $!";
```

I need to parameterize `USERID=MYUSER/MYPA55W0RD` and hide this in a hidden file or something. Can someone show me how to set this up?

Comment: [This question from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365492/weird-issue-with-netsshexpect-in-perl-script) has an example of reading a password from a hidden file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to something like this:

```
my $date_string= strftime '%Y%m%d',gmtime;
my $par_file = "/tmp/$schema-$date_string.par";
my $creds = `cat .secretfile`;
chomp($creds);

open my $par_fh, '>', $par_file or die "$par_file: opening for write: $!";
print $par_fh << PAR;
USERID=$creds
DIRECTORY=DMPDIR
SCHEMA=$schema
DUMPFILE=$schema-$date_string.dmp
CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
LOGFILE=$schema-$date_string.log
PAR
close $par_fh
    or die "$par_file: closing after write: $!";
```

Where .secretfile has a string like 'scott/tiger' in it.  Note that this is not very robust, so feel free to strengthen it to meet your policy.  For example, make sure the file exists and has mode no bigger than 0600 to reduce the chances that it's been tampered with.